# QlikView Dynamic Date Comparisons

Tags: qlikview

I’m relatively new to Qlikview and have a dataset that shows metrics by date.

This data spans two years and the requirement is to have a comparison/variance that is dynamic and can handle the date filters on the report.

For example if the user selects 2018 this field should show the current date compared to the previous year date. Similar for Quarters, months, weeks and weekdays.

Ideally it should always show for the previous period. They’ve had this created in Excel but it can’t handle the amount of records and I suggested QlikView as I had created some other Dashboards in it.

I have tried set analysis though I struggle to see how that would fit into one expression.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would say you would need two expressions, one without a set analysis (that would be filtered by your current selection) and one with a set analysis to guarantee that you only get today's value. This would be something like :

```
Sum($<[Date Field] = {"$(=Date(Today(), 'DD/MM/YYYY'))}>} [Value Field])
```

Check the date format conversion to see if it matches the date format of your field.